# PLSQL function if not available do else

Tags: oracle, encryption, plsql

In my oracle 11 environment I have declared following function (successfully, no errors).

```
create or replace function s2_encrypt(paramToEncrypt in VARCHAR2, encrypt8BYTEKey in RAW)
    return RAW is encryptedReturnValue RAW (2000);
    encryptionMode number := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES128 + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;
begin
    encryptedReturnValue := dbms_crypto.encrypt(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW(paramToEncrypt, 'AL32UTF8'), encryptionMode, encrypt8BYTEKey);
    return encryptedReturnValue;
end;
/
```

found here: http://anujktyagi.blogspot.ch/2012/12/oracle-using-dbmscrypto-package-for.html

I am deploying this on several servers, some of which only run Oracle version 8 / 9 -> in which case I want to just copy the value (instead of decrypting it).

How would I extend the above function so that it can be deployed both in Oracle 10+ and lower (in later case just copy paste the value and not encrypt)?

Something like

```
create or replace function s2_encrypt(paramToEncrypt in VARCHAR2, encrypt8BYTEKey in RAW)
    return RAW is encryptedReturnValue RAW (2000);
    encryptionMode number := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES128 + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;
begin

...
if !dbms_crypto.encrypt exit ???
...

    encryptedReturnValue := dbms_crypto.encrypt(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW(paramToEncrypt, 'AL32UTF8'), encryptionMode, encrypt8BYTEKey);
    return encryptedReturnValue;
end;
/
```

Comment: Conditional compiling is not available in Oracle 8/9, so the answers below can only be used on Oracle 10g+ databases, which does not apply to your environment.

Comment: That would be correct, but then how does the DBMS_DB_VERSION even output anything less than 10 if it is not available (in anything less than 10)?

Comment: Maybe the package existed before 10gr2, but conditional compilation was only introduced in 10gr2.

Comment: The compilation fails before 10. I need two functions one for 9 and less and the "normal" for 10+. I tried ----create or replace function s2_encrypt(paramToEncrypt in VARCHAR2, encrypt8BYTEKey in RAW)
    return paramToEncrypt AS encryptedReturnValue
begin
    return paramToEncrypt;
end;
/

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional compilation
using package DBMS_DB_VERSION or some of your constants

```
$IF DBMS_DB_VERSION.ver_le_9_1 $THEN
   return paramToEncrypt ;
$ELSE
   encryptedReturnValue := dbms_crypto.encrypt(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW(paramToEncrypt, 'AL32UTF8'), encryptionMode, encrypt8BYTEKey);
    return encryptedReturnValue;
$END
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_dbver.htm#CCHHJAGH ... this article sais the "DBMS_DB_VERSION" is only available in Oracle 10+, so this would not work in anything less, am I incorrect? I need it to work on Oracle 8 / 9

Answer (score 1):

The most sensible approach would be to use two separate versions of the function - one for version 8/9 and one for 10.

That being said, the following approach *should* work (untested, I don't have access to any instances running Oracle 10 or lower):

- check the database version (either by checking the *existence* of `DBMS_DB_VERSION` or by parsing the output of `PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION` or `V$VERSION` which - to the best of my knowledge - already existed in version 8).
- use dynamic SQL to either call `dbms_crypto` or return the string unchanged (since your package won't compile on 8/9 if you reference `dbms_crypto` directly)

Example (untested):

```
create or replace function s2_encrypt(paramToEncrypt  in VARCHAR2,
                                      encrypt8BYTEKey in RAW) return RAW is
  encryptedReturnValue RAW(2000);
  objectCount          pls_integer;
begin
  select count(*)
    into objectCount
    from all_objects
   where object_name = 'DBMS_CRYPTO';
  -- Oracle 8/9: return string unchanged
  if objectCount = 0 then
    encryptedReturnValue := paramToEncrypt;
  else
    execute immediate '
          declare
            encryptionMode number := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES128 + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;
          begin
            :encryptedReturnValue := dbms_crypto.encrypt(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW(:paramToEncrypt, ''AL32UTF8''), encryptionMode, :encrypt8BYTEKey);
          end;'
      using out encryptedReturnValue, in paramToEncrypt, in encrypt8BYTEKey;
  end if;
  return encryptedReturnValue;
end;
```

**Usage (11g - 8i apparently did not have UTL_I18N, see comments)**

```
select s2_encrypt(
  'hello world', 
  UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ('8232E3F8BDE7703C', 'AL32UTF8')) 
from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks Frank. The function saved in my Oracle 8 environment without errors. When I test the function I do get an "invalid column name" error". see http://oi63.tinypic.com/zti6b4.jpg. And in Oracle 11 it also gives an error (ORA-06536: IN bind variable bound to an OUT position). Ill make two different functions for 10 and less!

Comment: @DavidDunham The error you're getting in 8i is related to the usage of the `utl_i18n` package in your test query - presumably, that package didn't exist in 8i. I've fixed the error in Oracle 11 by explicitly stating the IN / OUT role of the bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conditional Compilation available from Oracle 10g Release 1.

See https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/conditional-compilation-10gr2

In older versions you can just use a normal IF-ELSE statement

```
DECLARE
   v1   VARCHAR2 (10);
   v2   VARCHAR2 (10);
BEGIN
   DBMS_UTILITY.db_version (v1, v2);

   IF SUBSTR (v1, 1, INSTR (v1, '.', 1)-1) < 10 THEN
      returnvalue paramToEncrypt;
    ELSE
      returnValue := dbms_crypto.encrypt(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW(paramToEncrypt, 'AL32UTF8'), encryptionMode, encrypt8BYTEKey);
    END;
return returnValue; 
END;
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_dbver.htm#CCHHJAGH ... this article sais the "DBMS_DB_VERSION" is only available in Oracle 10+, so this would not work in anything less, am I incorrect? I need it to work on Oracle 8 / 9

Comment: I have updated my answer now using DBMS_UTILITY.db_version to check for version.